Changing Integration Bounds to Compute Contour Integral
So I have an Integral of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)\frac{1 - e^{ibx}}{x} }{E - x^2} dx$ where $f(x)$ is analytic everywhere and goes to zero as $R \to \infty$ for a semicircular contour on the Upper Half plane. So I want to use contour Integration to compute the Integral by using a contour on the Upper-Half plane, but the integration bounds $0$ to $\infty$ makes this very difficult. So I was wondering whether it is possible for me change the integration bounds to be $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ by introducing an analytic step function to the integral something of the form $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\frac{x}{\delta}}}$ so that my integral changes to $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\frac{x}{\delta}}} \frac{f(x)\frac{1 - e^{ibx}}{x} }{E - x^2} dx$. Will this give me the desired result after contour integration? because it seems this is just tantamount to only picking the pole on the positive real axis of the expression $E - x^2$ for the residue theorem, so I have some doubts as to whether this approach is justified. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please check if $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{x}{\delta}}}$ exists for all real $x$. It's not clear what $\delta$ is and I doubt it would help solve the problem. Also, knowing the restrictions on $E$, like if it's a real number, a complex number, a complex number in the upper half plane, etc., helps in figuring out what contour you need to construct to avoid the poles.

E is a real number. The limit $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\frac{x}{\delta}}}$ exist everywhere except maybe at $x=0$ since this is a model of a step function. But I can potentially keep $\delta$ finite but close to zero to approximate the integral? if this model will give me my desired result, which is what I am trying to figure out, since it does not seem like the conventional way of doing things

The two-sided limit for $\delta$ doesn't exist no matter if $x>0$ or $x<0$. If you take $\delta \to 0^+$ then the limit equals $1$ for $x>0$ and equals $0$ for $x<0$.

When $\delta \to 0^-$ for $x>0$, the limit equals $0$. When $\delta \to 0^-$ for $x<0$, the limit equals $1$. No matter if $x$ is positive or negative, the limit as $\delta$ approaches $0$ from both sides doesn't exist.
